# Suddenly VB.Net Iterator Function Wont Compile?

Tags: .net, vb.net, iterator, async-ctp

For months now, using the Async CTP Ithe following compiled successfully:

```
    Public Shared Iterator Function FindVisualChildren(Of T As DependencyObject)(ByVal depObj As DependencyObject) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    If depObj IsNot Nothing Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj) - 1
            Dim child As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i)
            If child IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf child Is T Then

                Yield CType(child, T)
            End If

            For Each childOfChild As T In FindVisualChildren(Of T)(child)

                Yield childOfChild
            Next childOfChild
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

Suddenly, this is no longer the case. Visual Studio no longer appears to recognise the syntax and squiggles Function with 'End of Statement Expected'.

Recently, my machine was left on (shame on me) with Visual Studio open and it was shutdown automatically to install some Winows Updates. SInce then, I have been unable to compile the solution. I went to a backup copy of my solution as of 2 weeks ago just to make sure I didn't goof something up and I'm seeing the same issue.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing the .Net Framework Async CTP as well.

From what I can tell, recently, I received several >net Framework 4 Updates and Security Updates.

I'm hoping that someone else ay be able to shed some light on this and save me a wasted day on the phone with MS.

Comment: Do other parts of async work okay?

Comment: I was able to compile and run a couple of the samples (for example, the NetFlix one from the Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples\(VB 101) Tutorial walkthrough folder.) Currently, I'm using Async only for the purpose of gaining the Iterator and Yield capabilities in VB.

Comment: If the other async samples work, that suggests the compiler itself is okay... very odd.

Comment: The samples I've seen so far don't demonstrate the Iterator or Yield functionality. It is interesting though that they do compile. It's also interesting that Visual Studio Editor is now confused b the syntax of the new function since the reboot / updates. I'm not sure what files are responsible for the editing syntax so I'm not sure where to begin researching.

Answer (score 0):

In your Function definition you have an error. Please check the documentation for declaring Functions in VB. I guess you have got it mixed up with C# or some other programming language.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sect4ck6.aspx

The word Iterator should not be used between Shared and Function because the Function's return value is given at the end of the Function with ... As IEnumerable(Of T).

The Iterator proceduremodifiers is only available for Visual Studio 11 and hence will normally not compile with VS 10 or lower:

[Iterator Proceduremodifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh156569%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You're looking at the wrong version; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sect4ck6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Then the Visual Studio used should be Version 11 with the 4.5.Net Framework for compiling. I don't have VS 2011 and hence can't test this code.